# How to Enable firewall for apache2 in Linux?

Tags: firewall

While i'm trying to enable firewall for Apache2 in Linux Operting system using following command `sudo ufw allow in "Apache"` After I checked whether the firewall in enable or not using the command `sudo ufw status`   But it still in inactive and How can I enable . I'm facing [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zrYE.png).

I want to enable firewall and the status as active like `Firewall is active and enabled on system startup`

Comment: To enable on boot: `sudo systemctl enable ufw`.   To start now: `sudo systemctl start ufw`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable ufw:

sudo ufw enable

By default, ufw provides pre-configured application profiles, including one for Apache. You can enable the Apache profile to allow HTTP and HTTPS traffic:

sudo ufw allow 'Apache'

ufw should automatically start on system boot by default. However, if you want to ensure it starts on system startup, you can use the following command:

sudo systemctl enable ufw